# Rails test triggers Sidekiq warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have the following method in a Sidekiq worker:

```
  def self.schedule_edits(course:, editing_user:, enrollment_results:)
    puts editing_user.id
    perform_async(course.id, editing_user.id, enrollment_results)
  end
```

I have a controller test that, when it calls this code throws the following warning:

```
WARN: Job arguments to MassEnrollmentWorker do not serialize to JSON safely. This will raise an error...
```

I have read up on the warning [HERE](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices) and I'm guessing that enrollment_results is the offending argument. However, when I run the test and output enrollment_results, here is what I see:

```
{"FirstUser"=>{:success=>"User added to course."}, "SecondUser"=>{:success=>"User added to course."}, "NotARealUserOnWikipedia"=>{:failure=>"Not an existing user."}
```

This appears to be a valid hash, so what is the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the part about Symbols.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple

> The arguments you pass to perform_async must be composed of simple JSON datatypes: string, integer, float, boolean, null(nil), array and hash. This means you must not use ruby symbols as arguments.

Comment: I was reading this as you should not pass symbols to perform_async like `SomeWorker.perform_async(:quote_id)`. Are you saying that the nested symbols like `:success` is what is causing this?

Comment: JSON doesn't know what a Symbol. Doesn't matter how deep you nest it.

Answer (score 1):

On my case I just needed to change the format of my hashmap to the string rocket => style.

From:

```
 Sidekiq::Client.push('class' => 'RecordOrderJob', 'args' => { foo: 'bar' })
```

to:

```
Sidekiq::Client.push('class' => 'RecordOrderJob', 'args' => { 'foo' => 'bar' })
```

just avoid symbols in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity; I fixed this by changing way the hash was build from:

```
{"FirstUser"=>{:success=>"User added to course."}, "SecondUser"=>{:success=>"User added to course."}, "NotARealUserOnWikipedia"=>{:failure=>"Not an existing user."}
```

to...

```
{"FirstUser"=>{"success"=>"User added to course."}, "SecondUser"=>{"success"=>"User added to course."}, "NotARealUserOnWikipedia"=>{"failure"=>"Not an existing user."}
```